# Red cross on OneDrive folder but everything is up to date

Tags: windows-10, onedrive, cloud-storage

I am using the OneDrive personal version. Only the top OneDrive folder in the file explorer has the red cross. All other folders or files seem up to date without any issues. The OneDrive icon in the tray is the "white cloud", which also shows no error. I have already tried the "Unlink the PC" option and sign in to the Microsoft Account again. But the issue persists.

How do find where is the issue?

[image: Screenshot]
[image: version]

Comment: Please refer to this article "[Fix OneDrive sync problems](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/fix-onedrive-sync-problems-207e983e-146d-404c-a994-672ef29e1f90?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)", you may try to reset OneDrive.